# I voted to close a question, and it told me the comment was removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, popups

I decided to take a look at some First posts in the review queue. This caused me to stumble across [this review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3960255). All is cool, and I decided to vote to close it. Go through the dialog, push the button, and a nice popup. Wait, what does that message say?

> [image: This comment has been removed]

Errr, ok? I didn't remove a comment though...

Comment: What close reason did you use?  Could it be some kind of interference with the automatic "possible duplicate of …" comments?

Comment: Reproduced. My guess is that something isn't checking for success when the request returns, and guess what flag error constant happens to coincide with the uninitialized/default 0 value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build `2014.2.3.1913` on meta and `2014.2.3.1343` on sites.